# Would the speed of an object keep increasing if it keeps falling infinitely? Please check details

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, wormholes

Assuming "A" and "B" to be two wormholes (Einstein-Rosen Bridge) inside the Earth's atmosphere, and Warmhole B be the opening to Warmhole A, would the speed of an object keep increasing if it enters Warmhole B falling from Point 1, and comes out of Warmhole A, and keeps falling infinitely? Would the speed keep increasing forever or become constant after some point, assuming that the object would not be destroyed by the Infinite Fall? What would happen if the object is capable of increasing its speed, like a rocket/spacecraft, and whenever it enters Wormhole B, it turns off its engine, but doesn't apply breaks. Then when it exits Wormhole A, it retains the speed at which it entered Wormhole B, and further uses its engine to increase its speed?

[image]

Comment: An object can never increase its speed above or in fact to the speed of light. There are multiple of answers on this page concerning maximum achievable speeds which you could regatd for an explanation

Comment: You are assuming that passing through the wormhole does not affect the potential energy. Unless you can specify exactly how your wormhole works, i.e. the spacetime geometry inside it, you cannot make ths assumption.

Comment: Passing through this wormhole *does* increase potential energy (as I've outlined in my answer); but I don't think the OP assumed that it didn't...

Comment: Methinks someone has been playing [*Portal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_%28video_game%29) a bit too much recently.

Answer (score 1):

The key point in your scenario as that your two wormholes are *inside* the atmosphere, meaning your object will reach terminal velocity and stay at a constant but relativistically slow speed :(

But don't worry, if we modify this problem so that the wormholes are outside the atmosphere, we don't need to worry about air resistance. If we consider only the Newtonian spproximation, your object will continue to accelerate without bound. However, special relativity tells us that nothing can ever reach the speed of light.

Your object will initially start to accelerate at 9.8 m/s^2 (or slightly less depending on how far your object is away from the Earth), but as it speeds up its acceleration gradually slows down until your ball is traveling nearly as fast as light.

The story isn't over yet, because, although your speed is only increasing slightly, the energy that would otherwise be used to increase your object's speed would be used to increase your objects mass (via E=mc^2), and hence its momentum. So what? Well, you probably didn't initally drop your object perfectly at rest. Any amount of horizontal velocity at all (even 1μm/s) will result in your object missing the bottom portal within a few years at most. This would be bad.

With so much momentum, the atmosphere would barely slow down the object at all. However, as explained in [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/) article, the air would actually fuse with your object, quickly pulverising it and generating a lot of dangerous radiation. The real trouble starts when your object (or whatever's left of it) hits the ground. As explained in [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/) article, an object traveling that fast would lead to some nasty consequences. It would pulverise the ground breaking whole continents and wiping out most (if not all) life on Earth.

How did it get all this energy because of gravity? You might ask. Well, gravity didn't actually give you your energy. Gravity just *transforms* gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy. The real culprit (or rather, culprits) are the portals. By instantly transporting your object from one location to a higher one, they are giving it potential energy. This means (unfortunately for people trying to destroy Earth) it would take an equal amount (or probably more) energy to run the portals.

Anyway, have a nice day, and I hope this helped you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a worm hole, we can set up another idealised situation where we know the mechanics of everything. 
Say we have an infinite plane of mass, and an object of rest mass $m_0$ falling from a close to infinite height above, with the whole area permeated by an atmosphere similar to Earth's.

This infinite plane of mass causes the gravitational field to point toward it everywhere at $90^{\circ}$, and it accelerates objects at $9.8ms^{-2}$.

The object starts at rest, and the plane starts accelerating it. Luckily we have an atmosphere, and the collisions between the object and all the little particles floating around prevent it from gaining enough momentum to have to bring in special relativity. This causes the object to accelerate slower and slower and finally have constant velocity - its terminal velocity.

Assuming the object is geometrically simple (a sphere?) we can set up an equation of the force to tell us when the object reaches this velocity.

In the direction toward the plane we have the force from gravity, $F_G=mg$.
In the opposite direction, we have the force from drag, given by the drag equation: 
$$F_D=\frac{\rho u^2 C_D A}{2}$$

Where $\rho$ will be the mass density of the atmosphere, $u$ is the velocity of the atmosphere relative to the object (in this case it'll be the opposite to the object's speed), $C_D$ is the drag coefficient of the object which you can find calculated for given shapes, $A$ is the area of the object projected onto a plane perpendicular to the direction of fluid flow.

We can now set up an equation of motion for the object:

$$F=F_G-F_D$$
$$ma=mg-\frac{\rho v^2 C_D A}{2}$$
$$a=g-\frac{\rho v^2 C_D A}{2m}$$

Now, we want to find terminal velocity, when $a=0$.

$$g=\frac{\rho v^2 C_D A}{2m}$$
Solve for v:
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{\rho C_D A}}$$

There we go, we have our terminal velocity.

Now, if you had no atmosphere, the object would keep accelerating infinitely, but to a limit in velocity thanks to special relativity.

The rest mass of the object is $m_0$. The effective mass of the object is $\gamma m_0$, where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor:
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

We have $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$ as $v \rightarrow c$, and because of the relation $m=\gamma m_0$, $m\rightarrow \infty$.

This means that it gets harder and harder to accelerate an object as the velocity of it increases, so in absence of atmosphere your object will increase in velocity, and approach but never reach the speed of light.